# What are the differences between split and rar?

Tags: files, filesystems, split, rar

I am used to raring files -- but I am looking for something faster. I see that there is a "[split](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm#01)" command. How does this command compare to `rar`? What is are the differences between `split` and `rar`?

Comment: What makes you think they are even similar? Just run `man split` and `man rar`. One splits a file into pieces, the other compresses it. They have nothing to do with each other. This is like asking what's the difference between a cow and a mouse. They're both mammals but apart from that...

Comment: @terdon So, that is the answer, right?

Comment: @terdon: Well, for you that is clear, but there is a reason this question is asked. You may not find it interesting, but it is a clear stated question. You can downvote it, but it should not be closed.

Comment: @Bernhard no offense is meant to the OP but this is a question that will not help future readers: i) the programs are not at all similar, what's the connection between splitting and compressing? ii) 5 minutes of web searching would have shown the OP what the programs do iii) simply reading the first 4 lines of `man split` and `man rar` would have done the same. The OP now has an answer so there is no reason to keep this Q since it is so unlikely to ever help anyone else. Whatever combination of misunderstandings led to this question are not likely to occur again.

Comment: @terdon Why did you not downvote the question then? The hover button says "No research effort" and "not useful", which is a reason to downvote, not to close, imo.

Comment: @Bernhard let's not do this here. Ping me in [chat] or post a meta question, I'd be happy to explain my reasoning in either place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

split is a traditional UNIX tool, that does one job only—splitting files. If you had a bunch of files to archive to individual disks, you might do it like this:

```
 ____________________
|     FILESYSTEM     |                 _________               ____________
| dir1/      dir2/   |      tar       |         |    gzip     |            |
|   file1      file3 | -------------->| ARCHIVE |------------>| COMPRESSED |
|   file2      file4 |                |_________|             |   ARCHIVE  |
|____________________|                                        |            |
                                                              |____________|
                                                                    |
                                                                    | s
                                                                    | p
                                                                    | l
                                                                    | i
                                                                    | t
                                                                    |
               +----------------+----------------+------------------+
               |                |                |
              \|/              \|/              \|/
          ____________     ____________     ____________
         |            |   |            |   |            |
         | COMPRESSED |   | COMPRESSED |   | COMPRESSED |
         | ARCHIVE    |   | ARCHIVE    |   | ARCHIVE    |   . . .
         | DISK 1     |   | DISK 2     |   | DISK 3     |
         |____________|   |____________|   |____________|
```

You use `tar` to combine a bunch of files into one archive; you use `gzip` to make that archive smaller by compressing it; and you finally use `split` to cut that compressed archive into chunks that fit on your disks. The advantage here is that you can easily switch out parts—say, you could use `bzip2` or `xz` to compress your archive. Or `cpio` to make your archive.

`rar` (and also `zip`) come from the DOS/Windows world, where you don't normally chain together tools. So, they actually combine an archiver (like tar), a compressor (like gzip), and a file splitter (like split) into one tool. The advantage is that they can three parts have more knowledge of the other—say, you could avoid splitting a single file across disks (which is near impossible with the distinct programs).

Answer (score 2):

split splits files, the size remains the same. rar reduces the size.

Comment: Well, it reduces the size, unless the file is already compressed like in a mp3 or movie. - In this case it is perfectly valid to use split, as it will be faster and produce (slighly) smaller files.

Comment: Rar is a compressions tool similar to zip and 7z.